# False error "not a git repository"

Tags: git, bash, scripting

I'm trying to make sure in my bash script that I'm inside top-level git repository

I'm receiving following error:

```
export GIT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
cd "$GIT_DIR"
git status
fatal: Not a git repository: ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GIT_DIR` variable is used by git the same way the `--git-dir` option is. It tells git the location of the *repository*, **which is the `.git` directory within your working directory**.

If you `export GIT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git"`, it should work.

The thing that exporting a variable does is make it available as an *environment* variable to programs called by the shell. If you don't export it, then it's just a *shell* variable, and only visible within the context of your script, not the programs your script calls.  So ... setting GIT_DIR without an `export` hides it from the git command ... but once you export this magic, important variable, you confuse git because this *environment* variable is one that it considers important.

Comment: Nice explanation. I guess that this wouldn't work quite the same in bare repositories, and maybe the best solution is simply not to tamper with environment variables: `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"` would probably be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Tom. :) And yes, my usual strategy is to avoid use of variables for single-use of data. Command substitution possibly with a function work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `export` statement should fix it.

This works for me:

```
GIT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
cd "$GIT_DIR"
git status
```

Comment: Why would the presence of the `export` stop it from working?

Comment: my guess is that there is a different between "exportable" variables and non-exported variables.

Comment: I also thought that `$GIT_DIR` was a reserved variable used by git, but couldn't find evidence of it

Comment: It's a bad idea to use ALL_CAPS variable names and I don't see the point of `export`ing it here, but I don't see how either of those things would produce the behaviour that the OP reports and I cannot reproduce the issue on my system.